# ASP.NET connection to local DB not working

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am trying to connect to a local SQL Server database and It is not working, 
the connection String is

```
Dim connString As String = "server=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=AdventureWorks"
sqlConn.ConnectionString = connString
sqlConn.Open()
```

Comment: Thanks for the Quick replies!! I am new to .NET so I guess i need to keep reading...
I replaced the absolute path with "localhost" and its working now.
thanks again for the help!
Dim connString As String = "server=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=AdventureWorks"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server has to be a server name. If it's on the same box do localhost in lieu of that long funky path.

Answer (score 4):

The `server` parameter looks mighty fishy to me.

If this is a SQL Server instance, you are trying to connect to the data file, not the database. It should be the network name of the computer that SQL Server is installed on.

I suggest taking a look at [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/) to see how it should look like.